# Element cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Olá, na verdade preciso de uma ajuda, tenho uma view que tem um elemento, só que essa view é usada para todas as páginas do meu site, só que, em alguma páginas eu não preciso do elemento,mas preciso de usar a view, é possível "blockar" esse elemento dessas páginas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só pegar o código do element e coloca-lo na pasta `/views/elements`

> Não esqueça de salvar com a extensão **.ctp**

Para utiliza-lo, use na sua view: `$this->element('nome_do_elemento')`. Use-a somente nas views que quiser ;)

Comment: não é isso  ele quer saber, ele quer saber como mostrar a view em umas páginas e outras não

Comment: O que você disse não faz sentido. Ele so pode ter elements em views ou em arquivos separados. Se tem em arquivos separados ele obviamente sabe como usar na view que quer, então ele tem na propria view. MInha explicação responde.

Comment: olha esa parte da pergunta "só que, em alguma páginas eu não preciso do elemento,mas preciso de usar a view"

Comment: Porque ele tem um element imbutido na view. Se ele separar esse elements em arquivos como citei acima pode utiliza-lo nas views que quiser. Da uma lida antes de comentar mais algo: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/views.html

Comment: Eu conheço a documentação de cabo a rabo, o que estou dizendo é que aparentemente não supre a necessidade dele, pelo o q eu entendi da pergunta, ele usa a view em todas as páginas, mas na view há um elemento que não precisa estar em todas as páginas, vou postar minha resposta sobre o que eu entendi da pergunta.

Comment: Então poste sua resposta e deixa ele rescolher. A opção de negativar a resposta está a sua disposição. Encerro por aqui.

Comment: tenho uma view que engloba 80 páginas no meu site, só que recentemente, inclui mais 5 páginas com essa view, mas não quero usar o elemento que tem na view, só a view.

Comment: Então minha solução é a ideal para você :)

Answer (score 0):

Já foi resolvido, dupliquei o *layout* que o `controller` da `view` usava, depois instanciei o elemento no *layout* que a `view` usava, e não na `view`. Depois mudei nas páginas que eu não queria usar o *layout* para o *layout* duplicado (sem o `element`), e agora está rodando limpo.

Comment: seria interessante colocar isso como comentário na sua pergunta, afinal de contas isso não é uma resposta, mas então eu realmente entendi o que precisa, em breve posto uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar o nome da página atual em `$this->name` (na view);

Depois disso você cria um *array* com todas as página onde o elemento não irá aparecer e faz uma verificação antes de chamar o *element* na sua *view*;

```
// Array com os nomes das páginas que o elemento não deve aparecer
$paginas = array("page1", "page2", "page2", "page3");
// Verifica se a página atual está entre as e não deve aparecer
if (!in_array($this->params['action'], $paginas))){
    // imprime o elemento
    echo $this->element('nome_do_elemento');
}
```